# How can I repeat specific block of C# code in my View using javascript and should that even be done like that or?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, view, controller

I'm working on small MVC application, and when view is loaded there is notification about how many messages are new in inbox (unread messages and it looks like this:),
[image]

also in different div it is possible to read message so that number which is notifing how many unread messages are there will be decreased. In our example from 14 number will be changed to 13.

But when I click on that letter (number 13) all unread messages should be shown as dropdown and I can see still 14 messages, even if there is number written "13".

That value did not updated because view did not render again, so I am wondering is it possible on click on that letter with number, to call method which is retrieving unread messages from database and to populate that so my dropdown with unread messages would be allways updated, if 13 is written show me 13 messaged and not 14 becuse view did not loaded again and acctual data from database is not updated.

This is the code where I'm repeating (showing unread messages from database) so I need somehow to repeat this code everytime when someone clicks on letter so that's how I could get real data from database?

```
       <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:GetAllUnreadMessages('@LoggedInUser.Id');" class="dropdown-toggle info-number" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="visibility:@visibility;">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                        @if (LoggedInUser != null)
                        {
                            // HERE I AM SHOWING ICON LETTER AND NUMBER OF UNREAD emails ON TOP OF
                            int unredEmails = EmailController.GetNumberOfUnreadEmails(LoggedInUser.Id);
                            if (unredEmails > 0)
                            {
                                <span class="badge bg-red" id="inboxunredEmails">@unredEmails</span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span class="badge bg-green">@unredEmails</span>
                            }

                        }
                        @*<span class="badge bg-green">2</span>*@
                    </a>

                    // HERE I AM SHOWING UNREAD MESSAGES AS DROPDOWN 
                    <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list" role="menu">
                        @if (LoggedInUser != null)
                        {
                            int unredEmails = EmailController.GetNumberOfUnreadEmails(LoggedInUser.Id);
                            if (unredEmails > 0)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < unredEmails; i++)
                                {
                                    <li>
                                        <a>
                                            <span class="email">
                                                Unread Email number: @i;
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                }
                            }
                         }
                    </ul>
</li>
```

//I am wondering here is it ok for my method `GetUnreadEmails` to stay `ActionResult` as a return type or how can I return data from that controller to get it here and loop them and generate each "email" when it is clicked on letter to check how many unread emails is there?

```
   <script>
    //var GetAllUnreadEmails = function (userId) {
    //    if (userId) {
    //        $.ajax({
    //            url: "Email/GetUnreadEmails",
    //            method: "GET",
    //            data: {emailId:userId},
    //            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //            success: function (data) {

    //            },
    //            error: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //                alert("error: Error!");
    //            },
    //            failure: function (response) {
    //                alert("failure: Error!");
    //            }
    //        });
    //    }
    //}
</script>
```

Here is my `GetUnreadEmails` method from my `Controller`:

```
 public ActionResult GetUnreadEmails(Guid emailId)
  {
     if (User.Id != null)
     {
        List<Emails> resultList = EmailController.GetUnreadEmailsByUserId(User.Id);
        return View(resultList);
     }
     return View("Error, not found!");
  }
```

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script>
            var GetAllUnreadEmails = function (userId) {
                if (userId) {
                   $.ajax({
                       url: "Email/GetUnreadEmails",
                       method: "GET",
                        data: {emailId:userId},
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       success: function (data) {
                                   $('YourdivId').html(data[0].count)//check property in console
                        },
                       error: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("error: Error!");
                       },
                       failure: function (response) {
                           alert("failure: Error!");
                       }
                   });
                }
            }
        </script>


        public ActionResult GetUnreadEmails(Guid emailId)
          {
var count=null;
             if (User.Id != null)
             {
                List<Emails> resultList = EmailController.GetUnreadEmailsByUserId(User.Id);
    count=resultList.count();
                     }
             return Json(count, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
          }
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a javascript function with  ajax call in separate js file & call this method GetNumberOfUnreadEmails with userid parameters using ajax,you can call that javascript function wherever you want by referencing that file.

Comment: create a json array of result & parse it in client side public JsonResult GetUnreadEmails(Guid emailId)
  {
     if (User.Id != null)
     {
        List<Emails> resultList = EmailController.GetUnreadEmailsByUserId(User.Id);
       
     }
     return Json(resultList,JsonRequestbehaviour.AllowGet);
  }